# How to improve SQL view with many joins

Tags: sql, performance, join

I'm quite new to SQL, I needed to create a data source which includes data from many different tables. I wrote following script. It works for low amount of data but when data size improves,it becomes impossible to get the data via this query. How can i improve this script, what might be the possible bottlenecks and keypoints ? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT     
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK, dbo.IDW_PROJECT_DATA.CODE + ' - ' + 
   dbo.IDW_PROJECT_DATA.DESCRIPTION AS PROJECT, 
   dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.CODE + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.DESCRIPTION AS PRJ_ALTERNATIVE, 
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.BOQ_NO, 
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE_FK AS BUDGETCODE,  
   dbo.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE.DESCRIPTION AS BC_DESCR, 
   dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.CODE AS ACTIVITY_ID, 
   dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.DESCRIPTION AS ACTIVITY_DESCR, dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.REFERENCE, 
   dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.OUTLINE_SPEC1, dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.UOM AS ITEM_UOM, 
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.COST_CODE, 
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.COMMODITY_CODE, 
   CASE 
       WHEN IDW_COSTDETAIL.COMMODITY_CODE IS NULL 
         THEN IDW_COST_CODE.DESCRIPTION 
         ELSE IDW_COMMODITIES.DESCRIPTION 
   END AS SUBITEM_DESCR, 
   dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.AQ_QUANTITY / (DATEDIFF(day, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE) + 1) AS ITEM_AQ, 
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.QUANTITY_BASED_AQ / (DATEDIFF(day, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE) + 1) AS SUBITEM_AQ, 
   CASE 
       WHEN IDW_COSTDETAIL.COMMODITY_CODE IS NULL 
         THEN IDW_COST_CODE.UOM 
         ELSE IDW_COMMODITIES.UOM 
   END AS SUBITEM_UOM, 
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.COST / (DATEDIFF(day, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE) + 1) AS UNIT_COST, 
   CASE 
      WHEN IDW_COSTDETAIL.COMMODITY_CODE IS NULL 
        THEN IDW_COST_CODE.CURRENCY 
        ELSE IDW_COMMODITIES.ESTIMATE_CURRENCY 
   END AS CATALOG_CUR, 
   dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.IQ_QUANTITY / (DATEDIFF(day, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE) + 1) AS ITEM_IQ, 
   dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL_IQ.QUANTITY / (DATEDIFF(day, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE) + 1) AS SUBITEM_IQ, 
   dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE, DATEDIFF(day, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE) AS DURATION, 
   dbo.SQLCALENDAR.DateKey AS FULLDATE, 
   dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.CODE + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.DESCRIPTION AS CODE, 
   dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_LVL1 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_DESC_LVL1 AS COC_LVL1, 
   dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_LVL2 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_DESC_LVL2 AS COC_LVL2, 
   dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_LVL3 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_DESC_LVL3 AS COC_LVL3, 
   dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_LVL4 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_DESC_LVL4 AS COC_LVL4, 
   dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_LVL5 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.COC_DESC_LVL5 AS COC_LVL5, 
   dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.CODE + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.DESCRIPTION AS COMMODITY, 
   dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_LVL1 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_DESC_LVL1 AS COM_LVL1, dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_LVL2 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_DESC_LVL2 AS COM_LVL2, 
   dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_LVL3 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_DESC_LVL3 AS COM_LVL3, dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_LVL4 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_DESC_LVL4 AS COM_LVL4, 
   dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_LVL5 + ' - ' + dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.COM_DESC_LVL5 AS COM_LVL5
FROM         
    dbo.IDW_PROJECT_DATA 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL ON dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK = dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK AND dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.CODE = dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_ACTIVITY_FK 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE ON dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE_FK = dbo.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE.CODE AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK = dbo.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE.IDW_PROJECT_FK ON dbo.IDW_PROJECT_DATA.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.IDW_PROJECT_FK 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE ON dbo.IDW_PROJECT_DATA.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK = dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.CODE AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK = dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.CODE AND dbo.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_CONTROLLING_CODE.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK = dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.CODE 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL ON dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.CODE = dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK AND dbo.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.ITEM_REFERENCE = dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.REFERENCE AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.BOQ_NO = dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.IDW_BOQ_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_COST_CODE ON dbo.IDW_PROJECT_DATA.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COST_CODE.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COST_CODE.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.COST_CODE = dbo.IDW_COST_CODE.CODE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES ON dbo.IDW_PROJECT_DATA.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.COMMODITY_CODE = dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES.CODE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V ON dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.COST_CODE = dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.CODE AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COST_CODE_HIER_V.IDW_PROJECT_FK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V ON dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.COMMODITY_CODE = dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.CODE AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COMMODITIES_HIER_V.IDW_PROJECT_FK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL_IQ ON dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_FK = dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL_IQ.IDW_PROJECT_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK = dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL_IQ.IDW_PROJECT_ALTERNATIVE_FK AND dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL.ID = dbo.IDW_COSTDETAIL_IQ.IDW_COSTDETAIL_FK 
CROSS JOIN
    dbo.SQLCALENDAR
WHERE     
    (dbo.IDW_BOQ_DETAIL.ITEM_KIND = 2) 
    AND (dbo.SQLCALENDAR.DateKey BETWEEN CONVERT(CHAR(8), dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.START_DATE, 112) AND CONVERT(CHAR(8), dbo.IDW_ACTIVITY.END_DATE, 112))
```

Comment: What is your database engine? And what is the need for this datasouce?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server (hence the dbo schema). God, it looks awful without aliases. Can you post the query plan? Also, you may want to consider splitting in two views: one indexed and another one on top of it with the LEFT and RIGHT joins.

Comment: Yes i'm using MSSQL Server. Now i got the execution plan. How can i post query plan ?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Run the script in SSMS, generate the execution plan, and create the indicies it suggests.

Comment: I have created suggested indices but the query still works very slow.